# Best method to store customer products

Tags: php, mysql

Well, I have here two methods to store the products purchased by my customers. But I'm wondering which I should use, so I'm here to get some opinions.
The first method is that:

```
try
{
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$HOST};dbname={$DB_NAME}", $USERNAME, $PASS);
}

$connection->beginTransaction();
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, customer_name, order_value, order_date)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

$query = $connection->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array
(
    $user_id,
    $user['user_name'],
    $order_value,
    $date
));

$id_of_respective_order = $connection->lastInsertId();

$sql = "INSERT INTO purchased_products (order_id, product_name, product_price, quantity)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

$query = $connection->prepare($sql);

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product)
{
    $query->execute(array
    (
        $id_of_respective_order,
        $product['product_name'],
        $product['product_price'],
        $product['quantity']
    ));
}

$connection->commit();
```

Now let's explain: with the method above I insert the order in one table and the purchased products in another table, and after I can show each one of the products purchased by any customer in an HTML table by using a `Foreign Key` `order_id` that I have in the `purchased_products` table.
Now I have the second method:

```
try
{
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$HOST};dbname={$DB_NAME}", $USERNAME, $PASS);
}

$connection->beginTransaction();
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, customer_name, order_value, order_date, purchased_products)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$purchased_products = null;

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product)
{
    $purchased_products .= "
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Price</th>
            <th>Quantity purchased</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{$product['product_name']}</td>
            <td>{$product['product_price']}</td>
            <td>{$product['quantity']}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    ";
}

$query = $connection->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array
(
    $user_id,
    $user['user_name'],
    $order_value,
    $date,
    $purchased_products
));

$connection->commit();
```

With this method I can show the products direct in the tables only with the table key `purchased_products`.
What method is the best? If I use the first one I can do operations with the value but... I've been researching and learned that the insert is made as a bottleneck. The purchase ID is assigned automatically and then I use lastInsertionId to determine which products belong to the previous purchase. But this means that if two people buy at the same time will have mistakes? One will have to wait for the operation to finish because the bottleneck or I will not have problems? Can I trust separate inserts or should I insert everything in one table as the second method?

Answer (score 1):

The first version is generally considered the superior method in a relational database.  You might want to consider just including a reference to the `Products` table instead of all the information about the product in `OrderProducts` (a better name than `PurchasedProducts`).  However, the values can change over time, so there is also a good reason for including the detail.

The second version is generally not applicable in this situation.  From the perspective of the database, the `ordered_products` column is a BLOB -- that is, it has no useful internal structure.  I mean, with effort, you can parse it out, either using string or XML functions.  But you should think really think of it as a binary type.

Why?  Normally, the following are types of questions that people want to ask:

- What are the top purchased products in the database?
- What is the average price of product X?
- What customers purchased both X and Y (although perhaps not in the same order)?
- What is the total price of the order based on the products that are in it?

All of these are easier to answer in the database with a separate table, `OrderProducts`.  You should take advantage of the database functionality, and use a junction table.

Comment: The second method also creates an overhead of 259 characters *per entry*, which is about 90% of the entire field, assuming a product name of "My example product", a price of "123.45£" and a quantity of "42". Over the entire row, that would probably scale down to 70% of wasted space, but that is still enormous.

Comment: I'm actually using the first method and doing the query using Foreign Key order_id as I mentioned in the question: `SELECT * FROM orders o, purchased_products pp WHERE o.customer_id LIKE {$user_id} AND pp.order_id = o.order_id ORDER BY o.order_id DESC` Is working fine. I just did not undestand what do you mean about this method in your answer. Can you be more specifc?

Comment: @Siguza . . . Extra space is often required for normalized data.  Foreign key references can ameliorate that problem.  You should learn proper `join` syntax.  The first method is preferable for answer questions about products and orders in the database.

Comment: @DrewPierce I didn't say anything against normalisation, but don't confuse it with needless redundancy. This is a particularly bad example for normalisation, since there are always going to be exactly 3 value, without exception. Still, normalisation could be done with an overhead of only 10 characters (`["","",""]`) using JSON, for example. I'm not saying that there should be no overhead or verbosity at all, I'm just  saying that the provided code is verbose far beyond reason.

Comment: Lol sorry i was running with Gordon's and thot u meant db not json sorry @Siguza

Comment: @Siguza . . . You would store the values in a reference table and just reference them.  Whether you want a reference table with three columns and one reference, or three reference tables is up to you.  If you take this approach, you might actually reduce the size of the data.